# ValueError while fitting a model even after imputation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imputation

I am using the Melbourne Housing Dataset from Kaggle to fit a regression model on it, with Price being the target value. You can find the dataset [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dipalira/Melbourne-Housing-Data-Kaggle/master/Data/Melbourne_housing_FULL.csv)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence import partial_dependence, plot_partial_dependence
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

cols_to_use = ['Distance', 'Landsize', 'BuildingArea']
data = pd.read_csv('data/melb_house_pricing.csv')
# drop rows where target is NaN
data = data.loc[~(data['Price'].isna())]
y = data.Price
X = data[cols_to_use]
my_imputer = Imputer()
imputed_X = my_imputer.fit_transform(X)

print(f"Contains NaNs in training data: {np.isnan(imputed_X).sum()}")
print(f"Contains NaNs in target data: {np.isnan(y).sum()}")
print(f"Contains Infinity: {np.isinf(imputed_X).sum()}")
print(f"Contains Infinity: {np.isinf(y).sum()}")

my_model = GradientBoostingRegressor()
my_model.fit(imputed_X, y)

# Here we make the plot
my_plots = plot_partial_dependence(my_model,       
                                   features=[0, 2], # column numbers of plots we want to show
                                   X=X,            # raw predictors data.
                                   feature_names=['Distance', 'Landsize', 'BuildingArea'], # labels on graphs
                                   grid_resolution=10) # number of values to plot on x axis
```

Even after using the Imputer from sklearn, I get the following error -

```
Contains NaNs in training data: 0
Contains NaNs in target data: 0
Contains Infinity: 0
Contains Infinity: 0
/Users/adimyth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/deprecation.py:85: DeprecationWarning: Function plot_partial_dependence is deprecated; The function ensemble.plot_partial_dependence has been deprecated in favour of sklearn.inspection.plot_partial_dependence in  0.21 and will be removed in 0.23.
  warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "partial_dependency_plots.py", line 29, in <module>
    grid_resolution=10) # number of values to plot on x axis
  File "/Users/adimyth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/deprecation.py", line 86, in wrapped
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/adimyth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/partial_dependence.py", line 286, in plot_partial_dependence
    X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, order='C')
  File "/Users/adimyth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 542, in check_array
    allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
  File "/Users/adimyth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 56, in _assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError(msg_err.format(type_err, X.dtype))
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

As, you can see when I print the number of NaNs in `imputed_X`, I get 0. So, why do I still get ValueError. Any help?

Comment: You only check for `nan` using `np.isnan`, not for infinity.

Comment: nan value is present in y, and you are using impute for only x.. you need to use impute for y as well

Comment: I've updated the question, you can see that neither the target or the training data contains NaNs or Infinity, yet I get ValueError. @amdex

Comment: In  plot_partial_dependency function pass value of x as imputed_X..

Answer (score 0):

Just change the code for plot_partial_dependence:

```
my_plots = plot_partial_dependence(my_model,       
                                   features=[0, 2], # column numbers of plots we want to show
                                   X=imputed_X,            # raw predictors data.
                                   feature_names=['Distance', 'Landsize', 'BuildingArea'], # labels on graphs
                                   grid_resolution=10) # num
```

It will work.

Comment: Thanks, it was so stupid of me to not use imputed_X while plotting :(